# Проблема с доступом к странице

Tags: apache

Собственно есть сайт, в нем папки, в папках фаил `site.com/.kek/lol/index.html` проблема в том, что фаил не найден на сервере, стоит Apache, как я понимаю проблема в точке, как можно её решить? (не удаляя точку)

Comment: Да нет ни каких проблем с отображением такого файла. Протестировано на локальном apache.

Comment: Может нужно доступ нужно проверить к папкам и файлу?

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко Доступ проверен, полностью открыт 777, по этому проблема не в этом